# LINQ query: could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated ...by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I'm experiencing exception thrown by linq query when I have more than two search parameters.

Esception is thrown when querying LocalityId saying:
 `.LocalityId == __searchValues_LocalityId_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

 First part of StackTrace contains very long and complex SQL query.


Here's my code sample:

```
private static IQueryable<AdvertisementDTO> SearchByValues(
        SearchOptions<AdvertisementDTO> options,
        IQueryable<AdvertisementDTO> data)      
{
        if (options?.SearchValues == null)
            return data;

        var searchValues = options.SearchValues;
        if (searchValues.PublisherUserId != Guid.Empty)
            data = data.Where(x => x.PublisherUserId.Equals(searchValues.PublisherUserId));
        if (searchValues.CountryId > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.CountryId == searchValues.CountryId);
        if (searchValues.LocalityId > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.LocalityId == searchValues.LocalityId);
        if (searchValues.SublocalityId > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.SublocalityId == searchValues.SublocalityId);
        if (searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_1_Id > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.AdministrativeAreaLevel_1_Id.Equals(searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_1_Id));
        if (searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_2_Id > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.AdministrativeAreaLevel_2_Id.Equals(searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_2_Id));
        if (searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_3_Id > 0)
            data = data.Where(x => x.AdministrativeAreaLevel_3_Id.Equals(searchValues.AdministrativeAreaLevel_3_Id));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValues.PostalCode))
            data = data.Where(x => x.PostalCode.Equals(searchValues.PostalCode));

        return data;
    }
```

I'm I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Could you try without some of the .Where clauses that use .Equals? Maybe they are not supported by the "C# to [db provider]" translator?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I had the same taught, but those .Equals() aren't called since I haven't provided those search values. So they have't been executed.

Comment: Is `searchValues.LocalityId` Nullable?

Comment: Thanks @Yitz! Just found it. my x.LocalityId were all null because I forgot to map it in repository.